# Off the shelf solutions for increasing SharePoint performance?

Tags: performance, 2007, architecture

What off the shelf solution/software do you use or recommend for enhancing SharePoint performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an off-the-shelf solution, although I haven't used it myself I'm also pretty impressed with what [Aptimize](https://web.archive.org/web/20120805022120/http://www.aptimize.com:80/) does. It performs a series of tweaks such as JS minification, generating image sprites, merging CSS files etc. to reduce the payload of the page.

Microsoft use it on sharepoint.microsoft.com, see [How we did it: Speeding up SharePoint.Microsoft.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20100605042253/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepoint/archive/2009/09/28/how-we-did-it-speeding-up-sharepoint-microsoft-com.aspx) for a write up.

If you're interesting in doing some of this stuff by hand, I wrote my [Checklist for Optimizing SharePoint Sites](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/06/my-checklist-for-optimizing-sharepoint.html) which discusses some of these issues and other SharePoint-specific steps which can be taken.

Comment: Great article! Helps better in understanding what qualities should an off the shelf solution have.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few ways to increase sharepoint peformance like External binary store and Remote blob store (SharePoint 2010). There are some third party solutions available like NCachePoint, StoragePoint which provide these features.

A good thing abount NCachePoint (http://www.alachisoft.com/ncachepoint/index.html) though is that it has some nice features like js minification, viewstate caching and list caching which really should help improve SharePoint performace.

Avepoint and aptmize are also there but I haven't ever tried. You may find some helpfull features there too.